# VBA: Returning Range.Find() result from a function

Tags: vba, excel, object

I need to encapsulate Range.Find() in a function, so I have the following (R1, C1 etc are all defined consts):

```
Function FindData(FindWhat As Variant) As Range
    Dim TheR As Range
    Set TheR = Range(Cells(R1, C1), Cells(R2, C2)).Find(FindWhat, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    FindData = TheR
End Function
```

I'm passing in a string, so the call is e.g.:

```
Set FirstCell = Call FindData("MyValue")
```

VBA pukes on the line `FindData = TheR` with the message `Object variable or With block variable not set`.  I've tried adding this if-block:

```
If (TheR Is Nothing) Then
    FindData = Nothing
Else
    FindData = TheR
End If
```

but it doesn't make any difference.  How can I return the value that Find() gives me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For object variables, you need to add the `Set` keyword, even in functions! ;)

So just add that at the end :

```
Function FindData(FindWhat As Variant) As Range
    Dim TheR As Range
    Set TheR = Range(Cells(R1, C1), Cells(R2, C2)).Find(FindWhat, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    Set FindData = TheR
End Function
```

And when you use the `Call` you won't get an output from the function, so you need to use parenthesis :

```
Set FirstCell = FindData("MyValue")
```

Comment: Oh, duh!  I should have realised _that_!  Many thanks :)

Comment: @skiaddict1 : I got the same trouble when I started the functions with objects! ;) Please accept the answer if your issue is solved ;)

Comment: you can omit `Dim TheR As Range` and `Set FindData = TheR` and simply go `Set FindData= Range(Cells(R1, C1), Cells(R2, C2)).Find(FindWhat, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)`